# auto-py-to-exe generated file not working properly

Tags: python, tkinter, auto-py-to-exe, tkcalendar

I made a program that takes data from excel files with a UI i made with tkinter, i wanted to convert this programm to a .exe file with auto-py-to-exe, the problem is when i execute the .exe file the calendar i made with tkvcalendar doesn't work, everything else works right except for the calendars i use in my UI

```
Running auto-py-to-exe v2.42.0
Building directory: C:\Users\aadri\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpc0qnzqmh
Provided command: pyinstaller --noconfirm --onedir --windowed --add-data "C:/Users/aadri/Desktop/Coding/comeback/Pyfiles/course_manager/Functions.py;." --hidden-import "tkcalendar" --hidden-import "Calendar"  "C:/Users/aadri/Desktop/Coding/comeback/Pyfiles/course_manager/Course_Manager.py"
Recursion Limit is set to 5000
Executing: pyinstaller --noconfirm --onedir --windowed --add-data C:/Users/aadri/Desktop/Coding/comeback/Pyfiles/course_manager/Functions.py;. --hidden-import tkcalendar --hidden-import Calendar C:/Users/aadri/Desktop/Coding/comeback/Pyfiles/course_manager/Course_Manager.py --distpath C:\Users\aadri\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpc0qnzqmh\application --workpath C:\Users\aadri\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpc0qnzqmh\build --specpath C:\Users\aadri\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpc0qnzqmh

85773 INFO: PyInstaller: 6.2.0
85781 INFO: Python: 3.12.0
85869 INFO: Platform: Windows-11-10.0.22621-SP0
85877 INFO: wrote C:\Users\aadri\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpc0qnzqmh\Course_Manager.spec
85908 INFO: Extending PYTHONPATH with paths
['C:\\Users\\aadri\\Desktop\\Coding\\comeback\\Pyfiles\\course_manager']
86532 INFO: Appending 'datas' from .spec
86539 INFO: checking Analysis
86546 INFO: Building Analysis because Analysis-00.toc is non existent
86549 INFO: Initializing module dependency graph...
86557 INFO: Caching module graph hooks...
86609 INFO: Analyzing base_library.zip ...
89787 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-encodings.py' from 'C:\\Users\\aadri\\Desktop\\Coding\\comeback\\excel\\Lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
91263 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-heapq.py' from 'C:\\Users\\aadri\\Desktop\\Coding\\comeback\\excel\\Lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
93236 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-pickle.py' from 'C:\\Users\\aadri\\Desktop\\Coding\\comeback\\excel\\Lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
95938 INFO: Caching module dependency graph...
96215 INFO: Running Analysis Analysis-00.toc
96229 INFO: Looking for Python shared library...
96243 INFO: Using Python shared library: C:\Users\aadri\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\python312.dll
96260 INFO: Analyzing C:\Users\aadri\Desktop\Coding\comeback\Pyfiles\course_manager\Course_Manager.py
96653 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-openpyxl.py' from 'C:\\Users\\aadri\\Desktop\\Coding\\comeback\\excel\\Lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\stdhooks'...
97305 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-xml.py' from 'C:\\Users\\aadri\\Desktop\\Coding\\comeback\\excel\\Lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
97358 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-xml.etree.cElementTree.py' from 'C:\\Users\\aadri\\Desktop\\Coding\\comeback\\excel\\Lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
99274 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-babel.py' from 'C:\\Users\\aadri\\Desktop\\Coding\\comeback\\excel\\Lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
100029 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-zoneinfo.py' from 'C:\\Users\\aadri\\Desktop\\Coding\\comeback\\excel\\Lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\stdhooks'...
100093 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-sysconfig.py' from 'C:\\Users\\aadri\\Desktop\\Coding\\comeback\\excel\\Lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
100206 INFO: Analyzing hidden import 'Calendar'
100231 ERROR: Hidden import 'Calendar' not found
100235 INFO: Processing module hooks...
100249 WARNING: Hidden import "tzdata" not found!
100867 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-_tkinter.py' from 'C:\\Users\\aadri\\Desktop\\Coding\\comeback\\excel\\Lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
100876 INFO: checking Tree
100881 INFO: Building Tree because Tree-00.toc is non existent
100890 INFO: Building Tree Tree-00.toc
101050 INFO: checking Tree
101064 INFO: Building Tree because Tree-01.toc is non existent
101080 INFO: Building Tree Tree-01.toc
101112 INFO: checking Tree
101127 INFO: Building Tree because Tree-02.toc is non existent
101143 INFO: Building Tree Tree-02.toc
101908 INFO: Looking for ctypes DLLs
101935 INFO: Analyzing run-time hooks ...
101962 INFO: Including run-time hook 'C:\\Users\\aadri\\Desktop\\Coding\\comeback\\excel\\Lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks\\rthooks\\pyi_rth_inspect.py'
101978 INFO: Including run-time hook 'C:\\Users\\aadri\\Desktop\\Coding\\comeback\\excel\\Lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks\\rthooks\\pyi_rth__tkinter.py'
102096 INFO: Looking for dynamic libraries
102932 INFO: Extra DLL search directories (AddDllDirectory): []
102936 INFO: Extra DLL search directories (PATH): []
103309 WARNING: Library not found: could not resolve 'api-ms-win-crt-conio-l1-1-0.dll', dependency of 'C:\\Users\\aadri\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312\\python312.dll'.
103327 WARNING: Library not found: could not resolve 'api-ms-win-crt-stdio-l1-1-0.dll', dependency of 'C:\\Users\\aadri\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312\\python312.dll'.
103344 WARNING: Library not found: could not resolve 'api-ms-win-crt-process-l1-1-0.dll', dependency of 'C:\\Users\\aadri\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312\\python312.dll'.
103348 WARNING: Library not found: could not resolve 'api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll', dependency of 'C:\\Users\\aadri\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312\\python312.dll'.
103359 WARNING: Library not found: could not resolve 'api-ms-win-crt-heap-l1-1-0.dll', dependency of 'C:\\Users\\aadri\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312\\python312.dll'.
103375 WARNING: Library not found: could not resolve 'api-ms-win-crt-math-l1-1-0.dll', dependency of 'C:\\Users\\aadri\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312\\python312.dll'.
103392 WARNING: Library not found: could not resolve 'api-ms-win-core-path-l1-1-0.dll', dependency of 'C:\\Users\\aadri\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312\\python312.dll'.
103407 WARNING: Library not found: could not resolve 'api-ms-win-crt-time-l1-1-0.dll', dependency of 'C:\\Users\\aadri\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312\\python312.dll'.
103414 WARNING: Library not found: could not resolve 'api-ms-win-crt-locale-l1-1-0.dll', dependency of 'C:\\Users\\aadri\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312\\python312.dll'.
103424 WARNING: Library not found: could not resolve 'api-ms-win-crt-filesystem-l1-1-0.dll', dependency of 'C:\\Users\\aadri\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312\\python312.dll'.
103440 WARNING: Library not found: could not resolve 'api-ms-win-crt-environment-l1-1-0.dll', dependency of 'C:\\Users\\aadri\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312\\python312.dll'.
103456 WARNING: Library not found: could not resolve 'api-ms-win-crt-convert-l1-1-0.dll', dependency of 'C:\\Users\\aadri\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312\\python312.dll'.
103471 WARNING: Library not found: could not resolve 'api-ms-win-crt-string-l1-1-0.dll', dependency of 'C:\\Users\\aadri\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312\\python312.dll'.
103479 WARNING: Library not found: could not resolve 'api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll', dependency of 'C:\\Users\\aadri\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312\\DLLs\\_decimal.pyd'.
103486 WARNING: Library not found: could not resolve 'api-ms-win-crt-locale-l1-1-0.dll', dependency of 'C:\\Users\\aadri\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312\\DLLs\\_decimal.pyd'.
103502 WARNING: Library not found: could not resolve 'api-ms-win-crt-heap-l1-1-0.dll', dependency of 'C:\\Users\\aadri\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312\\DLLs\\_decimal.pyd'.
103508 WARNING: Library not found: could not resolve 'api-ms-win-crt-math-l1-1-0.dll', dependency of 'C:\\Users\\aadri\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312\\DLLs\\_decimal.pyd'.
103532 WARNING: Library not found: could not resolve 'api-ms-win-crt-stdio-l1-1-0.dll', dependency of 'C:\\Users\\aadri\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312\\DLLs\\_decimal.pyd'.
103539 WARNING: Library not found: could not resolve 'api-ms-win-crt-convert-l1-1-0.dll', dependency of 'C:\\Users\\aadri\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312\\DLLs\\_decimal.pyd'.
103548 WARNING: Library not found: could not resolve 'api-ms-win-crt-string-l1-1-0.dll', dependency of 'C:\\Users\\aadri\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312\\DLLs\\_decimal.pyd'.
103554 WARNING: Library not found: could not resolve 'api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll', dependency of 'C:\\Users\\aadri\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312\\DLLs\\_hashlib.pyd'.
103565 WARNING: Library not found: could not resolve 'api-ms-win-crt-string-l1-1-0.dll', dependency of 'C:\\Users\\aadri\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312\\DLLs\\_hashlib.pyd'.
103571 WARNING: Library not found: could not resolve 'api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll', dependency of 'C:\\Users\\aadri\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312\\DLLs\\_lzma.pyd'.
103595 WARNING: Library not found: could not resolve 'api-ms-win-crt-heap-l1-1-0.dll', dependency of 'C:\\Users\\aadri\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312\\DLLs\\_lzma.pyd'.
103601 WARNING: Library not found: could not resolve 'api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll', dependency of 'C:\\Users\\aadri\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312\\DLLs\\_bz2.pyd'.
103610 WARNING: Library not found: could not resolve 'api-ms-win-crt-heap-l1-1-0.dll', dependency of 'C:\\Users\\aadri\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312\\DLLs\\_bz2.pyd'.
103624 WARNING: Library not found: could not resolve 'api-ms-win-crt-stdio-l1-1-0.dll', dependency of 'C:\\Users\\aadri\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312\\DLLs\\_bz2.pyd'.
103641 WARNING: Library not found: could not resolve 'api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll', dependency of 'C:\\Users\\aadri\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312\\DLLs\\unicodedata.pyd'.
103649 WARNING: Library not found: could not resolve 'api-ms-win-crt-stdio-l1-1-0.dll', dependency of 'C:\\Users\\aadri\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312\\DLLs\\unicodedata.pyd'.
103657 WARNING: Library not found: could not resolve 'api-ms-win-crt-string-l1-1-0.dll', dependency of 'C:\\Users\\aadri\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312\\DLLs\\unicodedata.pyd'.
103666 WARNING: Library not found: could not resolve 'api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll', dependency of 'C:\\Users\\aadri\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312\\DLLs\\select.pyd'.
103672 WARNING: Library not found: could not resolve 'api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll', dependency of 'C:\\Users\\aadri\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312\\DLLs\\_socket.pyd'.
103687 WARNING: Library not found: could not resolve 'api-ms-win-crt-stdio-l1-1-0.dll', dependency of 'C:\\Users\\aadri\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312\\DLLs\\_socket.pyd'.
103703 WARNING: Library not found: could not resolve 'api-ms-win-crt-string-l1-1-0.dll', dependency of 'C:\\Users\\aadri\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312\\DLLs\\_socket.pyd'.
103719 WARNING: Library not found: could not resolve 'api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll', dependency of 'C:\\Users\\aadri\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312\\DLLs\\_zoneinfo.pyd'.
103735 WARNING: Library not found: could not resolve 'api-ms-win-crt-string-l1-1-0.dll', dependency of 'C:\\Users\\aadri\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312\\DLLs\\_zoneinfo.pyd'.
103742 WARNING: Library not found: could not resolve 'api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll', dependency of 'C:\\Users\\aadri\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312\\DLLs\\_elementtree.pyd'.
103752 WARNING: Library not found: could not resolve 'api-ms-win-crt-string-l1-1-0.dll', dependency of 'C:\\Users\\aadri\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312\\DLLs\\_elementtree.pyd'.
103763 WARNING: Library not found: could not resolve 'api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll', dependency of 'C:\\Users\\aadri\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312\\DLLs\\pyexpat.pyd'.
103783 WARNING: Library not found: could not resolve 'api-ms-win-crt-heap-l1-1-0.dll', dependency of 'C:\\Users\\aadri\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312\\DLLs\\pyexpat.pyd'.
103799 WARNING: Library not found: could not resolve 'api-ms-win-crt-environment-l1-1-0.dll', dependency of 'C:\\Users\\aadri\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312\\DLLs\\pyexpat.pyd'.
103815 WARNING: Library not found: could not resolve 'api-ms-win-crt-stdio-l1-1-0.dll', dependency of 'C:\\Users\\aadri\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312\\DLLs\\pyexpat.pyd'.
103830 WARNING: Library not found: could not resolve 'api-ms-win-crt-convert-l1-1-0.dll', dependency of 'C:\\Users\\aadri\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312\\DLLs\\pyexpat.pyd'.
103839 WARNING: Library not found: could not resolve 'api-ms-win-crt-utility-l1-1-0.dll', dependency of 'C:\\Users\\aadri\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312\\DLLs\\pyexpat.pyd'.
103862 WARNING: Library not found: could not resolve 'api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll', dependency of 'C:\\Users\\aadri\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312\\DLLs\\_ssl.pyd'.
103878 WARNING: Library not found: could not resolve 'api-ms-win-crt-stdio-l1-1-0.dll', dependency of 'C:\\Users\\aadri\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312\\DLLs\\_ssl.pyd'.
103894 WARNING: Library not found: could not resolve 'api-ms-win-crt-string-l1-1-0.dll', dependency of 'C:\\Users\\aadri\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312\\DLLs\\_ssl.pyd'.
103910 WARNING: Library not found: could not resolve 'api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll', dependency of 'C:\\Users\\aadri\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312\\DLLs\\_tkinter.pyd'.
103926 WARNING: Library not found: could not resolve 'api-ms-win-crt-stdio-l1-1-0.dll', dependency of 'C:\\Users\\aadri\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312\\DLLs\\_tkinter.pyd'.
103942 WARNING: Library not found: could not resolve 'api-ms-win-crt-string-l1-1-0.dll', dependency of 'C:\\Users\\aadri\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312\\DLLs\\_tkinter.pyd'.
103958 WARNING: Library not found: could not resolve 'api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll', dependency of 'C:\\Users\\aadri\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312\\VCRUNTIME140.dll'.
103974 WARNING: Library not found: could not resolve 'api-ms-win-crt-heap-l1-1-0.dll', dependency of 'C:\\Users\\aadri\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312\\VCRUNTIME140.dll'.
103990 WARNING: Library not found: could not resolve 'api-ms-win-crt-stdio-l1-1-0.dll', dependency of 'C:\\Users\\aadri\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312\\VCRUNTIME140.dll'.
104001 WARNING: Library not found: could not resolve 'api-ms-win-crt-convert-l1-1-0.dll', dependency of 'C:\\Users\\aadri\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312\\VCRUNTIME140.dll'.
104021 WARNING: Library not found: could not resolve 'api-ms-win-crt-string-l1-1-0.dll', dependency of 'C:\\Users\\aadri\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312\\VCRUNTIME140.dll'.
104035 WARNING: Library not found: could not resolve 'api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll', dependency of 'C:\\Users\\aadri\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312\\DLLs\\libcrypto-3.dll'.
104051 WARNING: Library not found: could not resolve 'api-ms-win-crt-heap-l1-1-0.dll', dependency of 'C:\\Users\\aadri\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312\\DLLs\\libcrypto-3.dll'.
104060 WARNING: Library not found: could not resolve 'api-ms-win-crt-environment-l1-1-0.dll', dependency of 'C:\\Users\\aadri\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312\\DLLs\\libcrypto-3.dll'.
104072 WARNING: Library not found: could not resolve 'api-ms-win-crt-stdio-l1-1-0.dll', dependency of 'C:\\Users\\aadri\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312\\DLLs\\libcrypto-3.dll'.
104098 WARNING: Library not found: could not resolve 'api-ms-win-crt-convert-l1-1-0.dll', dependency of 'C:\\Users\\aadri\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312\\DLLs\\libcrypto-3.dll'.
104108 WARNING: Library not found: could not resolve 'api-ms-win-crt-string-l1-1-0.dll', dependency of 'C:\\Users\\aadri\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312\\DLLs\\libcrypto-3.dll'.
104131 WARNING: Library not found: could not resolve 'api-ms-win-crt-filesystem-l1-1-0.dll', dependency of 'C:\\Users\\aadri\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312\\DLLs\\libcrypto-3.dll'.
104140 WARNING: Library not found: could not resolve 'api-ms-win-crt-utility-l1-1-0.dll', dependency of 'C:\\Users\\aadri\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312\\DLLs\\libcrypto-3.dll'.
104163 WARNING: Library not found: could not resolve 'api-ms-win-crt-time-l1-1-0.dll', dependency of 'C:\\Users\\aadri\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312\\DLLs\\libcrypto-3.dll'.
104176 WARNING: Library not found: could not resolve 'api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll', dependency of 'C:\\Users\\aadri\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312\\DLLs\\libssl-3.dll'.
104192 WARNING: Library not found: could not resolve 'api-ms-win-crt-stdio-l1-1-0.dll', dependency of 'C:\\Users\\aadri\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312\\DLLs\\libssl-3.dll'.
104210 WARNING: Library not found: could not resolve 'api-ms-win-crt-convert-l1-1-0.dll', dependency of 'C:\\Users\\aadri\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312\\DLLs\\libssl-3.dll'.
104226 WARNING: Library not found: could not resolve 'api-ms-win-crt-string-l1-1-0.dll', dependency of 'C:\\Users\\aadri\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312\\DLLs\\libssl-3.dll'.
104257 WARNING: Library not found: could not resolve 'api-ms-win-crt-filesystem-l1-1-0.dll', dependency of 'C:\\Users\\aadri\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312\\DLLs\\libssl-3.dll'.
104286 WARNING: Library not found: could not resolve 'api-ms-win-crt-utility-l1-1-0.dll', dependency of 'C:\\Users\\aadri\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312\\DLLs\\libssl-3.dll'.
104302 WARNING: Library not found: could not resolve 'api-ms-win-crt-time-l1-1-0.dll', dependency of 'C:\\Users\\aadri\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312\\DLLs\\libssl-3.dll'.
104318 WARNING: Library not found: could not resolve 'api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll', dependency of 'C:\\Users\\aadri\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312\\DLLs\\tk86t.dll'.
104333 WARNING: Library not found: could not resolve 'api-ms-win-crt-heap-l1-1-0.dll', dependency of 'C:\\Users\\aadri\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312\\DLLs\\tk86t.dll'.
104350 WARNING: Library not found: could not resolve 'api-ms-win-crt-math-l1-1-0.dll', dependency of 'C:\\Users\\aadri\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312\\DLLs\\tk86t.dll'.
104382 WARNING: Library not found: could not resolve 'api-ms-win-crt-stdio-l1-1-0.dll', dependency of 'C:\\Users\\aadri\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312\\DLLs\\tk86t.dll'.
104397 WARNING: Library not found: could not resolve 'api-ms-win-crt-convert-l1-1-0.dll', dependency of 'C:\\Users\\aadri\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312\\DLLs\\tk86t.dll'.
104413 WARNING: Library not found: could not resolve 'api-ms-win-crt-string-l1-1-0.dll', dependency of 'C:\\Users\\aadri\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312\\DLLs\\tk86t.dll'.
104429 WARNING: Library not found: could not resolve 'api-ms-win-crt-utility-l1-1-0.dll', dependency of 'C:\\Users\\aadri\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312\\DLLs\\tk86t.dll'.
104439 WARNING: Library not found: could not resolve 'api-ms-win-crt-time-l1-1-0.dll', dependency of 'C:\\Users\\aadri\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312\\DLLs\\tk86t.dll'.
104462 WARNING: Library not found: could not resolve 'api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll', dependency of 'C:\\Users\\aadri\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312\\DLLs\\tcl86t.dll'.
104472 WARNING: Library not found: could not resolve 'api-ms-win-crt-heap-l1-1-0.dll', dependency of 'C:\\Users\\aadri\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312\\DLLs\\tcl86t.dll'.
104493 WARNING: Library not found: could not resolve 'api-ms-win-crt-environment-l1-1-0.dll', dependency of 'C:\\Users\\aadri\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312\\DLLs\\tcl86t.dll'.
104504 WARNING: Library not found: could not resolve 'api-ms-win-crt-math-l1-1-0.dll', dependency of 'C:\\Users\\aadri\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312\\DLLs\\tcl86t.dll'.
104524 WARNING: Library not found: could not resolve 'api-ms-win-crt-stdio-l1-1-0.dll', dependency of 'C:\\Users\\aadri\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312\\DLLs\\tcl86t.dll'.
104541 WARNING: Library not found: could not resolve 'api-ms-win-crt-convert-l1-1-0.dll', dependency of 'C:\\Users\\aadri\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312\\DLLs\\tcl86t.dll'.
104556 WARNING: Library not found: could not resolve 'api-ms-win-crt-string-l1-1-0.dll', dependency of 'C:\\Users\\aadri\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312\\DLLs\\tcl86t.dll'.
104587 WARNING: Library not found: could not resolve 'api-ms-win-crt-utility-l1-1-0.dll', dependency of 'C:\\Users\\aadri\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312\\DLLs\\tcl86t.dll'.
104601 WARNING: Library not found: could not resolve 'api-ms-win-crt-time-l1-1-0.dll', dependency of 'C:\\Users\\aadri\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312\\DLLs\\tcl86t.dll'.
104782 INFO: Warnings written to C:\Users\aadri\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpc0qnzqmh\build\Course_Manager\warn-Course_Manager.txt
104896 INFO: Graph cross-reference written to C:\Users\aadri\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpc0qnzqmh\build\Course_Manager\xref-Course_Manager.html
105060 INFO: checking PYZ
105073 INFO: Building PYZ because PYZ-00.toc is non existent
105083 INFO: Building PYZ (ZlibArchive) C:\Users\aadri\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpc0qnzqmh\build\Course_Manager\PYZ-00.pyz
106012 INFO: Building PYZ (ZlibArchive) C:\Users\aadri\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpc0qnzqmh\build\Course_Manager\PYZ-00.pyz completed successfully.
106063 INFO: checking PKG
106086 INFO: Building PKG because PKG-00.toc is non existent
106101 INFO: Building PKG (CArchive) Course_Manager.pkg
106156 INFO: Building PKG (CArchive) Course_Manager.pkg completed successfully.
106183 INFO: Bootloader C:\Users\aadri\Desktop\Coding\comeback\excel\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\bootloader\Windows-64bit-intel\runw.exe
106197 INFO: checking EXE
106213 INFO: Building EXE because EXE-00.toc is non existent
106229 INFO: Building EXE from EXE-00.toc
106245 INFO: Copying bootloader EXE to C:\Users\aadri\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpc0qnzqmh\build\Course_Manager\Course_Manager.exe
106408 INFO: Copying icon to EXE
An error occurred while packaging
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\aadri\Desktop\Coding\comeback\excel\Lib\site-packages\win32ctypes\pywin32\pywintypes.py", line 33, in pywin32error
    yield
  File "C:\Users\aadri\Desktop\Coding\comeback\excel\Lib\site-packages\win32ctypes\pywin32\win32api.py", line 209, in BeginUpdateResource
    return _resource._BeginUpdateResource(filename, delete)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\aadri\Desktop\Coding\comeback\excel\Lib\site-packages\win32ctypes\core\cffi\_resource.py", line 114, in _BeginUpdateResource
    result = check_null(
             ^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\aadri\Desktop\Coding\comeback\excel\Lib\site-packages\win32ctypes\core\cffi\_util.py", line 78, in __call__
    self._raise_error(function_name)
  File "C:\Users\aadri\Desktop\Coding\comeback\excel\Lib\site-packages\win32ctypes\core\cffi\_util.py", line 89, in _raise_error
    raise exception
OSError: [WinError 225] No se pudo completar la operación porque el archivo contiene un virus o software potencialmente no deseado

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\aadri\Desktop\Coding\comeback\excel\Lib\site-packages\auto_py_to_exe\packaging.py", line 132, in package
    run_pyinstaller()
  File "C:\Users\aadri\Desktop\Coding\comeback\excel\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\__main__.py", line 198, in run
    run_build(pyi_config, spec_file, **vars(args))
  File "C:\Users\aadri\Desktop\Coding\comeback\excel\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\__main__.py", line 69, in run_build
    PyInstaller.building.build_main.main(pyi_config, spec_file, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\aadri\Desktop\Coding\comeback\excel\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 1069, in main
    build(specfile, distpath, workpath, clean_build)
  File "C:\Users\aadri\Desktop\Coding\comeback\excel\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 1009, in build
    exec(code, spec_namespace)
  File "C:\Users\aadri\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpc0qnzqmh\Course_Manager.spec", line 18, in <module>
    exe = EXE(
          ^^^^
  File "C:\Users\aadri\Desktop\Coding\comeback\excel\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\api.py", line 628, in __init__
    self.__postinit__()
  File "C:\Users\aadri\Desktop\Coding\comeback\excel\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\datastruct.py", line 184, in __postinit__
    self.assemble()
  File "C:\Users\aadri\Desktop\Coding\comeback\excel\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\api.py", line 741, in assemble
    self._retry_operation(icon.CopyIcons, build_name, self.icon)
  File "C:\Users\aadri\Desktop\Coding\comeback\excel\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\api.py", line 995, in _retry_operation
    return func(*args)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\aadri\Desktop\Coding\comeback\excel\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\utils\win32\icon.py", line 209, in CopyIcons
    return CopyIcons_FromIco(dstpath, [srcpath])
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\aadri\Desktop\Coding\comeback\excel\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\utils\win32\icon.py", line 143, in CopyIcons_FromIco
    hdst = win32api.BeginUpdateResource(dstpath, 0)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\aadri\Desktop\Coding\comeback\excel\Lib\site-packages\win32ctypes\pywin32\win32api.py", line 208, in BeginUpdateResource
    with _pywin32error():
  File "C:\Users\aadri\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\contextlib.py", line 155, in __exit__
    self.gen.throw(value)
  File "C:\Users\aadri\Desktop\Coding\comeback\excel\Lib\site-packages\win32ctypes\pywin32\pywintypes.py", line 37, in pywin32error
    raise error(exception.winerror, exception.function, exception.strerror)
win32ctypes.pywin32.pywintypes.error: (225, '', 'No se pudo completar la operación porque el archivo contiene un virus o software potencialmente no deseado')

Project output will not be moved to output folder
Complete.
```

This is the mesage i recived after using the auto-py-to-exe, i think it has relation with the last parte where it says that the operation couldn't be completed because the file has a potential virus

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk 
import Functions as fu
from tkinter import filedialog as fd
from tkcalendar import Calendar
import datetime, tkcalendar
```

Here is the imports i used for the file i was trying to convert, the library Functions is a file that i added before converting; also i have already tried to add tkcalendar as a missing import but it doesn't work

```
def get_starting_date():
     global starting_date
     selected_date = cal.get_date()
     starting_date_label.config(text=f"Selected starting date: {selected_date}")
     starting_date.set(selected_date)
     cal_window.destroy()

def show_starting_calendar():#This creates a toplevel window so the user selects a date more easily
     global cal_window
     cal_window = tk.Toplevel(main)
     cal_window.title("Select a date")

     global cal
     cal = Calendar(cal_window, selectmode="day", year=2023, month=1, day=1)
     cal.pack(pady=10)

     close_calendar = tk.Button(cal_window,text="Select date",font=("Tahoma",10),command=get_starting_date)
     close_calendar.pack(pady=10)

def get_ending_date():
     global ending_date
     selected_date = cal.get_date()
     ending_date_label.config(text=f"Selected ending date: {selected_date}")
     ending_date.set(selected_date)
     cal_window.destroy()

def show_ending_calendar():#This creates a toplevel window so the user selects a date more easily
     global cal_window
     cal_window = tk.Toplevel(main)
     cal_window.title("Select a date")

     global cal
     cal = Calendar(cal_window, selectmode="day", year=2023, month=1, day=1)
     cal.pack(pady=10)

     close_calendar = tk.Button(cal_window,text="Select date",font=("Tahoma",10),command=get_ending_date)
     close_calendar.pack(pady=10)
```

Here is one of the parts i use the calendar widget in my programm, the other ones are similar, like just using tags for creating events

```
import tkinter as tk 
from tkcalendar import Calendar

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("800x600")

cal = Calendar(root,selectmode="day", year=2023, month=1, day=1)
cal.pack(pady=10)

root.mainloop()

import tkinter as tk 
from tkcalendar import Calendar

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("800x600")

cal = Calendar(root,selectmode="day", year=2023, month=1, day=1)
cal.pack(pady=10)

root.mainloop()
```

Here is my **Minimal reproducible example**, is the Calendar widget that i have problems with

all of my program works fine except for the calendar widgets i made with tkcalendar, this widgets just don't appear but everything else made with normal tkinter and their funtionality works correctly, i went to the auto-py-to-exe FAQ but i didn't saw anything that could colve my problem, i tried adding the tkcalendar folder and in the hidden imports but it doesn't work, i don't know what to do

Comment: Can you provide a code snippet of the sections you use the calendar widgets for your UI? I'd advise you add an anti-virus exception for your project folder cause that seems to be affecting the packaging process. `auto-py-to-exe` is a gui wrapper for a tool called `pyinstaller`, also I'd advise switching to `pyinstaller` cause it's more frequently updated and has better documentation.

Comment: Thanks, how do i add antivirus exeption?

Comment: [Try this out](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/add-an-exclusion-to-windows-security-811816c0-4dfd-af4a-47e4-c301afe13b26)

Comment: I added multiple files and folders to the anti-virus exception but i keep getting the same result, also i tried using pyinstaller in the console and i had the same result as using auto-py-to-exe, the same error mesage

Comment: You added the root folder of your project yet you're still getting the virus error?

Comment: Yes, i also added the folder of the venv i was using and various files mentioned in the error mesage; i saw a question with similar problems that said to add ‘c:/Windows/system32/downlevel’ to the enviromenral variable if pyinstaller was having problems not founding a library but i don’t know how to do that

Comment: create a [mre].

Comment: Ok, i added the example

Comment: `Calendar` is not a module, it is a class inside `tkcalendar` module.

Answer (score 0):

With regard to the tkcalendar not working, I had a similar issue and needed to add babel.numbers (a dependency) to my hidden imports. This does not address the potential anti-virus problem.